# What causes this error: 554 5.7.1 [TPG-B01] Backscatter rejected to prevent DNSBL listings. Please reject mail during the SMTP session

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP script that attempts to send an email, but continually triggers this error on my local machine:

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 
554 5.7.1 [TPG-B01] Backscatter rejected to prevent DNSBL listings. 
Please reject mail during the SMTP session. For more information, 
see http://spamlinks.net/prevent-secure-backscatter.htm
```

Googling reveals almost nothing about what that error means, and the URL referenced appears to be down.  Does anyone know what causes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally tracked it down.

This error occurs when the **mail envelope sender** is empty, that is when it communicates with a remote SMTP server and sends something like this:

> `220 mail.tpg.com.au ESMTP (mail14) Sendmail ready.`
>   **`HELO localhost`**
>   `250 mail14.tpgi.com.au Hello [x.x.x.x] (may be forged), pleased to meet you`
>   **`MAIL FROM:<>`**
>   `250 2.1.0 <>... Sender ok`

Even though it says "Sender ok", it's *not* OK.  After sending the message, the 554 error above is triggered.

The solution is to ensure that PHP's `sendmail_from` setting is valid (and not empty).  You can do this in your `php.ini` file, like so...

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from=foo@bar.com
```

Or within your script...

```
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'foo@bar.com');
```

Hope that helps somebody else out there.  It took me hours to track this down.

Comment: who sane uses `mail()`?